# Scrapy gets partial data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm experiencing with Scrapy a little bit - my task is to get data from a crowd-funding site (I chose kickstarter.com). Now, I began by crawling a single page (starting from [here](https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?category_id=16&woe_id=0&sort=magic&seed=2569222&page=1)), and retrieving projects' links out of it, and then crawling to these links. For debugging purposes, I saved these links responses as html files. Here's my code:

```
import scrapy
import time
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class KsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "kickstarter"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.page = 1
        self.dbg = False


    start_urls = []
    num_pages = 1

    for i in range(num_pages):
        start_urls.append("https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?category_id=16&woe_id=0&sort=magic&seed=2569222&page=" + str(i+1) + "")

    def parse(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='lxml')
        candidates = list(soup.findAll('div', class_='js-react-proj-card'))

        urls = set()
        for c in candidates:
            # extracting the data-project dict
            data_project = json.loads(c.attrs['data-project'])
            urls.add(data_project['urls']['web']['project'])

        for url in urls:
            if self.dbg:
                print("Sleeping...")
                time.sleep(3)
                print("Request for url:", url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_contents)


    def parse_contents(self, response):
        filename = 'ksproj-%s.html' % self.page
        self.page += 1
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Unfortunately, the data that was saved is not complete - for example, [in this project](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/kobotix/real-racer-first-person-view-fpv-rc-driving-experi?ref=discovery), here's how it looks when I watch it using my browser:
[image]
this is exactly the missing part in my downloaded webpage (everything below this part of the page is present).

What can I do in order to have the full data? Thanks

Comment: Some parts of the page might be supposed to be loaded with ajax, that's why they're not showing up. Anyway, you might want to screnshoot your downloaded page

Comment: I figured out that it has something to do with javascript. My downloaded page contains simply a gray background instead of the contents in the image I uploaded

Comment: FYI while the content is configured to update frequently (via AJAX), the initial values are already included in the page source in HTML. E.g. you may search for "backers_count" in the retrieved HTML body.

Comment: I'll try to extract the data from there... thanks